# To test the accuracy of a predicted value against the known value

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, analysis, prediction

If I want to  assess the accuracy of a predicted value against the known value   would it be ok to do something like :

```
result =absolutevalue((known value -  predicted value)/known value) 
0.054 =absolutevalue((37 -  39)/37)
```

Because the result is close  to zero  this means its quite accurate 
And likewise  if I've a column of value know values and a column of predicted   predicted values could then do same  by

```
(cumulative known values - cumulative predicted values) /cumulative known values
```

It'd  be  helpful if someone could explain it because my model looks fairly accurate, but the scores it depicts are not accurate at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid evaluation of a model where the errors cancel each other. Exactly that could happen if you compares cumulative values with cumulative predictions.

Here is an example

```
> df <- data.frame(known = c(5,17,11,24), predict = c(10,12,15,17))
> df
  known predict
1     5      10
2    17      12
3    11      15
4    24      17
> 
> df$known - df$predict
[1] -5  5 -4  7
>
```

The *cumulative relative* difference is low...

```
> abs(sum(df$known) - sum(df$predict)) / sum(df$known)
[1] 0.052631579
```

... but if you calculate [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) you see you have more than 5 units difference in you prediction

```
> sqrt(mean((df$known - df$predict)^2))
[1] 5.3619026
```

... which normalized to the mean of your values is much higher

```
> sqrt(mean((df$known - df$predict)^2)) / mean (df$known)
[1] 0.37627387
```

You may also calculate the [Mean absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) with similar results

```
> sum(abs(df$known - df$predict)) / nrow(df)
[1] 5.25
```